# Can/Is the latest version of IdentityServer4 supports dynamic client add?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I assume I can build an additional API that registers users/apps/containers.

But is there a simpler way to accept multiple clients dynamically ?

That is for example, if my IDP is in the UK, and i would like to allow a predefined containers to "add themselves" to the client list of my IDP.

I achieved a simple "User -> Client -> IDP" authentication but would like to automate the process.

Thank you fellow coders.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes - but you'd have to create the mechanism to do so yourself.
If using a database to back your client storage (rather than using the default static/config file based in-memory store) then you're free to implement that any way you like.

In our solution we have an API that allows for this as well as a more limited self-serve UI capability.

There is an OpenID Connect spec for this that may provide some inspiration: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html

Comment: Thank you sir, 
after dabbing in the issues I found out that I have to use some combo of ASP.NET Core Identity And IdentityServer. I'm trying to apply that now.
Are they designed to work together if applied?.

Comment: There’s a level of integration available to get you up and running quickly but there’s no hard dependency and you’re free to implement your own membership functionality should you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you own client store using IClientStore interface.

Something like

```c#
internal class MyCustomClientStore : IClientStore
{
    public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can store client data anywhere you want, interface is pretty simple.
This implementation can be registered using DI with

```c#
services
   .AddIdentityServer()...
   .AddClientStore<MyCustomClientStore>()
```